# Rotate xtick_labels in Scilab

Tags: plot, rotation, axis, label, scilab

I created a bar chart in Scilab, and have changed the ticks from numbers to names of people. But changing to names makes them over-flow into each other and makes them unreadable. I found a solution on Matlab (XTickLabelRotation), but unfortunately that doesn't work for Scilab.

Is there another solution? I dug through axes_properties, and couldn't find anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Apparently, this is not supported yet. I tried a few things, including mathml style with rotation: no luck.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use [LaTeX ticks](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/math_rendering_features_in_graphic.html) with the latex [rotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93797/how-to-rotate-text-inline).